# Get reason for a spell-checker decision in VIM

Tags: vim, spell-checking

Is there a way to see, from within VIM, how a word was determined to be correctly or incorrectly spelled, for example, by displaying the spell file where it is listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in. You will have to write a function that fiddles with the `'spelllang'` and `'spellfile'` option values, and invoke `spellbadword()` to check whether it's still recognized. From that, you can deduce which source contains the definition.